# Device admin in android

Tags: android-ndk, android

In my app,I need to lock my phone when a particular SMS is received.I passed in retreiving the SMS content and checking with the preset command.The next task is to lock the screen...

For this I referred many blogs and sites,and atlast reached a conclusion in DeviceAdmin class section of android from Google codes...I treid the sample code...It works indpendantlly smooth.But i require to set a password for the lock and to programmatically lock the phone....

Please have a look at the [DEVICE ADMIN code section](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use [`resetPassword(String password, int flags)`](http://goo.gl/GDq1u) and then call  [`lockNow`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#lockNow%28%29)

Your device admin class will have to have [`USES_POLICY_RESET_PASSWORD`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DeviceAdminInfo.html#USES_POLICY_RESET_PASSWORD) and [`USES_POLICY_FORCE_LOCK`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DeviceAdminInfo.html#USES_POLICY_FORCE_LOCK)